# Python Chain of Responsibility and coroutine

Tags: python, coroutine

sorry if I write something stupid but I'm trying to solve an exercise on chain of responsibility and coroutine for an exam.

**The following is my code:**

```
import functools


def coroutine(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        generator = function(*args, **kwargs)
        next(generator)
        return generator

    return wrapper


@coroutine
def DefaultHandler(successor=None):
    while True:
        request = yield
        if any(isinstance(x, str) for x in request) or request[0] < 0 or len(request) != 2:
            print(f"Request {request} handled by Default_Handler: it was not possible to handle the request {request}")
        else:
            if successor is not None:
                successor.send(request)

@coroutine
def Handler_04(successor=None):
    while True:
        request = yield
        if isinstance(request[0], (int, float)) and 0 <= request[0] <= 4 and len(request) == 2:
            print(f"Request {request} handled by Handler_04")
        else:
            if successor is not None:
                successor.send(request)


@coroutine
def Handler_59(successor=None):
    while True:
        request = yield
        if isinstance(request[0], (int, float)) and 5 <= request[0] <= 9 and len(request) == 2:
            print(f"Request {request} handled by Handler_59")
        else:
            if successor is not None:
                successor.send(request)


@coroutine
def Handler_gt9(successor=None):
    while True:
        request = yield
        if isinstance(request[0], (int, float)) and request[0] > 9 and len(request) == 2:
            print(
                f"Message from Handler_gt9: it was not possible to handle the request {request}. Request modified")
            new_data = [request[0] - request[1], request[1]]
            if successor is not None:
                successor.send(new_data)
        else:
            if successor is not None:
                successor.send(request)


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.handler = Handler_04(Handler_59(Handler_gt9(DefaultHandler(None))))

    def delegate(self, requests):
        for request in requests:
            self.handler.send(request)


# Create a client object
client = Client()

# Create richieste to be processed.
requests = []

for i in range(0, 15, 2):
    requests.append([i, 7])

requests.append([-3, 4])
requests.append(["a", 2])
requests.append([1, 2, 4])
client.delegate(requests)
```

**Now, the program should print this:**

```
Request [0, 7] handled by Handler_04
Request [2, 7] handled by Handler_04
Request [4, 7] handled by Handler_04
Request [6, 7] handled by Handler_59
Request [8, 7] handled by Handler_59
Message from Handler_gt9: The request could not be handled [10, 7]. Request modified
Request [3, 7] handled by Handler_04
Message from Handler_gt9: The request could not be handled [12, 7]. Request modified
Request [5, 7] handled by Handler_59
Message from Handler_gt9: The request could not be handled [14, 7]. Request modified
Request [7, 7] handled by Handler_59
Request [-3, 4] handled by Default_Handler: request [-3, 4] could not be handled
Request ['a', 2] handled by Default_Handler: Request ['a', 2] could not be handled
Request [1, 2, 4] handled by Default_Handler: request [1, 2, 4] could not be handled
```

**But, when I get to this point**

```
"Message from Handler_gt9: The request could not be handled [10, 7]. Request modified"
```

My program ignores the new list created in Handler_gt9 and continues while I would like the new list to be passed to the right handler based on the values of the list, in the first case the list becomes [3,7] and should be managed by Handler_04 (instead I think it is sent to the Defalut_Handler which however does nothing because it only has to deal with lists in which there is a string or the first negative number)

What I would like to understand is what I'm doing wrong, keeping in mind that all the code from the Client class down was given to me with the exercise and should not be modified

Thanks to anyone who will waste 10-15 minutes to give me advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're doing things in the wrong order, as some debug prints would show you. Because of the way you build your chain, `DefaultHandler` gets put in the chain first, so your requests go from 04 to 59 to gt9 to Default. After gt9 modifies the request, there's nobody following who knows how to handle that result. Add `print('04:',request)` (etc) after each `request = yield` to see this in action.

If I reverse the order of the handlers in Client, it works as you expect.